# Rotating map overlays

Tags: android, overlay, hide, android-mapview

I am dealing with a overlays on mapview.

I have 2 types of them, lets say type *"One"* and *"Two"*

They both are overlayed on same or diffrent condition.

When are overlayed on same condition one overlaps the other. and earlier one hides behind the latter one.

I want to give option to user to cycle through these overlapped overlays if this overlapping case occurs.

Any solution?

Can overlay handle double taps ?

[image: Example]

Comment: please clear your question to a more extent

Comment: I hope this clears the scenario

Answer (score 0):

We have OnDoubleTapListener. But I am not sure whether it can be applied with overlays. Just give a try.

Please refer the [site](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-gesture/) for showing an eg for OnDoubleTapListener

Comment: Theres no DoubleTapListener in Overlay class. How should I achive that ?